# Zip google cloude storage file damage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, php-ziparchive

I use the following code to zip the google file, and the zip file is created successful, but after double clicked show error message as screenshot. How to I solve it?

```
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zipname = time() . ".zip"; // Zip name
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

        $files = array('http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/k8tmo5m0KZLJbZjLiSMHjefsjJXfQSS_r6julCj8LCW-OsOFf715YOlWvHE9Xze4Rm2gxsWhl9OCLLHsXyluyDFz4n1xRQHOijS3iOs',
            'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/hk_y_5BKSCJpNOqpCkq7mWTPzljo8kXmLf2qQR16K6HASfEeDu0yxNBcheFyjnFUCMOl6-fZiJlp4n4Kb_fhihUGyn58TUDRD1iECrur');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $zip->addFromString(basename($file), file_get_contents($file));
        }

        $zip->close();

        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipname);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
        readfile($zipname);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get that message once you downloaded the zip, or on the generated zip file on the server?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, no message at all. Zip download successful, but error message as screeshot when double click the file.